# Alternatives to malloc for dynamic memory allocations in CUDA kernel functions

Tags: cuda, malloc, gpu

I'm trying to compile my CUDA C code for a GPU with `sm_10` architecture which does not support invoking `malloc` from `__global__` functions.

I need to keep a tree for which the nodes are created dynamically in the GPU memory. Unfortunately, without `malloc` apparently I can't do that.

Is there is a way to copy an entire tree using `cudaMalloc`? I think that such an approach will just copy the root of my tree.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: The last part of your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by _copy an entire tree using `cudaMalloc`_? `cudaMalloc` is used only to allocate memory. Could you also explain why do you expect that by `cudaMalloc` you will only be able to copy the root of your tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the CUDA C Programming Guide

> Dynamic global memory allocation and operations are only supported by devices of
>   compute capability 2.x and higher.

For compute capability earlier than `2.0`, the only possibilities are:

1. Use `cudaMalloc` from host side to allocate as much global memory as you need in your `__global__` function;
2. Use static allocation if you know the required memory size at compile time;